# How to deploy cxf web service on jboss eap 6.1

Tags: eclipse, deployment, jboss

Hey guys I am trying to deploy my cxf web service on jboss-eap-6.1 but its not getting done.. I am providing the stack trace below:

```
16:37:30,821 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."GenericEnterpriseApplicationSkeleton.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."GenericEnterpriseApplicationSkeleton.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "GenericEnterpriseApplicationSkeleton.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011030: Could not configure component org.apache.cxf.wsn.client.Publisher
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.apache.cxf.wsn.client.Publisher
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:607)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:80)
    ... 6 more

16:37:30,854 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "GenericEnterpriseApplicationSkeleton.war" (runtime-name : "GenericEnterpriseApplicationSkeleton.war")
16:37:30,854 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "EAApplication.ear" (runtime-name : "EAApplication.ear")
16:37:30,855 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."GenericEnterpriseApplicationSkeleton.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."GenericEnterpriseApplicationSkeleton.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "GenericEnterpriseApplicationSkeleton.war"

16:37:31,036 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http:// 127.0.0.1:9990/management
16:37:31,037 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http:// 127.0.0.1:9990
16:37:31,037 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA (AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8) started (with errors) in 5102ms - Started 198 of 260 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 60 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Please do have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I got similar but not the exact error as mentioned by you. I solved it by bypassing the default Jboss Webservices implementation.

I commented out the following lines in the standalone.xml

```
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
```

and the subsystem

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
        <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
        <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
        <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
        <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
            <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
            </pre-handler-chain>
        </endpoint-config>
        <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
    </subsystem>
```

Please see the link on how I got the idea - https://developer.jboss.org/thread/221654. Hope this helps.