# Error in Deploying CXF web service on jboss-eap-6.1.1

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jboss

I have created java bean skeleton in eclipse using CXF and deploying it on Jboss 6.1.1 , but unable to deploy it getting the following error: (stack trace below). Have updated standalone.xml by commenting :

```
 <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
```

and

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
<modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
<wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
<endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
<endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
<pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
<handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
</pre-handler-chain>
</endpoint-config>
<client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
</subsystem>
```

### This was done resolve previous errors as suggested in other blog : [How to deploy cxf web service on jboss eap 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518486/how-to-deploy-cxf-web-service-on-jboss-eap-6-1)

cxf-beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<!-- <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" /> -->
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
<jaxws:endpoint xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/TestWS/"
    id="testws" implementor="org.example.testws.TestWSImpl" wsdlLocation="WEB-INF/TestWS.wsdl"
    endpointName="tns:TestWSSOAP" serviceName="tns:TestWS" address="/TestWSSOAP">
    <jaxws:features>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
    </jaxws:features>
</jaxws:endpoint>
</beans>
```

---

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>TestCXFProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
    <display-name>cxf</display-name>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

---

```
12:45:19,129 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testws': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1fce836' of type [org.example.testws.TestWSImpl] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.example.testws.TestWSImpl] for bean with name '(inner bean)#1fce836' defined in null; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.example.testws.TestWSImpl from [Module "deployment.TestCXFProjectEAR.ear.TestCXFProject.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.example.testws.TestWSImpl] for bean with name '(inner bean)#1fce836' defined in null; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.example.testws.TestWSImpl from [Module "deployment.TestCXFProjectEAR.ear.TestCXFProject.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1328) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:453) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.example.testws.TestWSImpl from [Module "deployment.TestCXFProjectEAR.ear.TestCXFProject.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:444) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:432) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:374) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:119) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:249) [spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1320) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Can you also post your spring beans and cxf xmls

Comment: Added cxf-beans.xml , web.xml being used in the pjt .

Comment: In contextConfigLocation param can you remove cxf-beans.xml or place an empty xml here

Comment: I updated the context-param tag in web.xml to -- <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
  </context-param> , but now I am getting the following error on deploying ... ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/TestCXFProject]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) JBWEB000289: Servlet cxf threw load() exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cxf' is defined

Comment: I am using apache-cxf-3.1.1 , eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) , jboss-eap-6.1.1

Comment: The issue is resolved now, the problem was the implementor in the endpoint tag in cxf-beans.xml was pointing to incorrect java file generated , it was pointing to TestWSImpl whereas the autogenerated file is TestWSSOAPImpl . On updating it , it started working , the  contextConfigLocation param can point to  cxf-beans.xml